# Не по глазам - что это значит?

Tags: значения, idioms

Здравствуйте. Никогда не встречал такого выражения, по контексту вроде бы со значением "сразу не увидел" или "прозевал" (например, просматривая список).
Есть ли примеры использования этого выражения в художественной литературе?

Comment: Похоже на что-то сугубо региональное, корявостью напоминающее "смеяться с кого-либо". Судя по гугловским результатам, выражение распространено в Новосибирске и его окрестностях.

Comment: two entries in Google Books: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%22 I've never come across this expression before but it's quite an interesting one, thanks for sharing!

Comment: было б здорово если бы привели несколько цитат с использованием этого выражения

Comment: Просто подсказали человеку, где в пользовательском интерфейсе искать нужную настройку, в ответ - "спасибо, нашёл. не по глазам было". Было всё ранним утром по московскому времени, весьма вероятно, что человек обращался с восточной части РФ.

Comment: @shabunc Примеры употребления: "да что-то не по глазам уже" - в качестве оправдания, когда что-то искал и не нашел, а другой пришел и сразу увидел. "Куда прешь, совсем не по шарам?!" - водитель пешеходу или наоборот. _(жил в Новосибирске когда-то)_

Comment: ...оказывается, люди за пределами Новосибирска могут и не слышать никогда фразы "Не по глазам"/"Не по шарам".

Answer (score 6):

Это очень интересная находка. Похоже, изначально это была редкая форма-аналог выражения "не по зубам".

"[Голубые глазки](http://az.lib.ru/m/mihajlow_m_l/text_0050.shtml)" (Михаил Михайлов, 1855)

> -- Ты сама не возьмёшься?
>
> Нет, Анна Карловна, не могу: не по глазам -- мелко очень. А непременно надо к пятнице?

"[Куплеты из водевилей](http://az.lib.ru/p/pawlow_n_f/text_0070.shtml)" (Николай Павлов, первая треть 19-го века)

> Всё звезды я считал, бывало \ Но мне они не по глазам \ Учился
> я, а толку мало, \ Не поклониться ли звездам?

"[Воспоминания о 1812-м годе](http://az.lib.ru/w/wjazemskij_p_a/text_1240.shtml)" (Пётр Вяземский, первая половина 19-го века)

> К чему такое презрение к читателям, как будто им не по глазам и не по росту картины более величавые

Сейчас же это ещё иногда с уклоном в "не по нраву", "не нравится". И действительно, похоже в выражение это употребляется в Сибири. Вот [цитата](http://www.stihi.ru/2011/08/23/1353) из стихотворения сибирской поэтессы:

> Что-то бывает, милый, не по глазам  средь чепуховин  вечных,
> беловоронных…

Comment: Спасибо! Выражение встретилось в чате тех.поддержки по програмному продукту - инженер указал, где искать настройку, на что пользователь поблагодарил и добавил это выражение. Я попробовал поискать в сети - но терпения не хватило.